# Using variadic templates to create a 2D array with variable column width?

Tags: c++, arrays, variadic-templates

Is it possible to create a "sparse" variable-length 2D array using only variadic templates and std::array?  By sparse, I mean that each row could have a variable amount of columns.

Ideally, I'd like to instantiate something like `VariableLengthTable<int,2,4,3>()` and have it create an array of arrays that would map to something like `{{0,1}, {0,1,2,3}, {0,1,2}}`.  I've seen SO posts that deal with variadic templates to create multidimensional arrays, but they are all symmetrical.

Note that I'm limited to zero-cost abstractions (e.g. std::array) as I'm working with a very memory constricted application.

Comment: I'm not really sure you need a variadic template to do that. Isn't `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or at least `std::array<std::vector<int>,N>` an option?

Comment: I'm looking for something that is zero-cost or very, very low cost. `std::vector` is unfortunately too big for our application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible in principle. Here's a bit to get you started:

```
template <class T, std::size_t... Dim>
using VariableLengthTable = std::tuple<std::array<T, Dim>...>;
```

This is a tuple of `std::array`s, each with a length specified by one of the template arguments.

Note that because the length of a `std::array` is part of its type, the first dimension cannot be an array, since its members would need different types. However, `std::tuple` works nicely. As long as you're willing to use `std::get<i>` instead of `[i]`, and restrict yourself to compile-time `i`s, you should be good.

If a compile-time `i` is not enough, you have two options:

**One**, use `VariableLengthTable` as above and add a runtime-to-compiletime conversion. Conceptually, something like this `switch`:

```
T& get(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
  switch (x) {
    case 0: return std::get<0>(varLenTable)[y];
    case 1: return std::get<1>(varLenTable)[y];
    case 2: return std::get<2>(varLenTable)[y];
    // and so on
  }
}
```

In reality, you'd probably need to compose this using recursion or inheritance to avoid a compile-time out-of-bounds access. [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) might help with that.

**Two**, store all the data in one sequential buffer and index into it at runtime. Something like this:

```
template <class T, std::size_t... Dim>
class VariableLengthTable
{
  static const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dim)> dims = {{ Dim... }};

  static const std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dim)> cumulDims = [](){
    std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Dim)> result;
    result[0] = 0;
    for (std::size_t idx = 1; idx < sizeof...(Dim); ++idx) {
      result[idx] = result[idx - 1] + dims[idx];
    }
    return result;
  }();

  std::array<T, cumulDims[sizeof...(Dim) - 1] + dims[sizeof...(Dim) - 1]> data;

public:
  T& get(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
  {
    return data[cumulDims[x] + y];
  }
};
```

The code above is to show the principle, not guaranteed to compile as-is.

Comment: Thanks, this might be exactly what I'm looking for.  I wasn't that familiar with tuples.  I'll give it a try!

Comment: Upon further inspection, I don't think I'll be able to use this in my application because of `std::tuple`'s restriction to compile-time `i`s.  It's a cool solution, but it unfortunately won't work functionally the same as an array of arrays at runtime.  I suppose I could add a template function to access cells in the form of `get<X>(Y)`, but in a space-constrained application, that doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: @WilliamMoy I've added two ways to support runtime indexing.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  #2 seems like the path I'll likely try.  Answered!